# Is it allowed for a non-practising Brahmin or non-Brahmin to chant the dhyanam to the Lalita Sahasranama including the nyasam?

Tags: lalita-sahasranama

I heard a recitation of the Lalita Sahasranama recently by Brahmasrī Śrījit Nampūtirī. I particularly loved the precedent to it that goes *om asyasrī lalitāsahasranāma mahāmantrasya*, etc. and the dhyanam, *sindūrārunavigrahāṁ trinayanām*, etc. The aforementioned *tantri* chanted it in the Kerala Brahmin *shaili* and it was really pleasant to the ears. I find myself repeating it to myself in that style at times.

I am not a Brahmin. I am not a brahmacāri either. If I chant those verses, will it bring bad karma upon me?

Comment: I guess only those who are upanita or initiated in Sri Vidya are qualified to read the sahasranama. And there is no purpose of reciting the viniyoga portion if someone is not going to read the sahasranama itself.

Comment: @Rickross Is it so? Many of my elders chant the Sahasranama like a prayer. Must I advise them against it?

Comment: No we should not advise someone not to read. The goddess will take care of any wrong doings that her devotees might have done. She is the supreme goddess and she knows the best. So we should never intervene. Although what I have said is not wrong too

Comment: Any stotra or any hymn or prayer is universally available to anyone to chant privately. It is only in the public viniyoga or prayoga that there are qualifications and restrictions. Similarly, anyone can gain knowledge of the meaning of mantras, but it is the viniyoga that needs proper training like for example, Vedas.